# Angularjs and web services

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

```
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="hello">

<script>            
function Hello($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting').
    success(function(data) {
        $scope.greeting = data;
    });
}
</script>
```

and I would like to print the content like this `{{greeting.id}}`.
the code snippet is going to get data in JSON format from "http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting" using angularjs. This isn't working in eclipse. Any ideas to make it work ?

Comment: Any errors in console? And what Angular version you are using? With 1.3.x you have to use modules.

Comment: What do you mean by `not working in Eclipse`?

Comment: no errors in console, its a web project so "{{greeting.id}}" appears exactly as it is

Comment: You would need to run the project in a browser, right?

Comment: If there are no errors and you `{{greeting.id}}` then you are not loading Angular script.

Comment: The data from the server isnt being displayed on the site. when i write a separate code just to read the json data using notepad, the data is shown but when i make changes to my web project via eclipse the changes arent reflecting

Comment: do you call the function 'Hello'? is it connected to the controller 'hello'? and the controller to the module 'myapp'?

Comment: @DavinTryon yes im running it on a firefox browser using a tomcat server

Comment: the function is called if the get request is a success yeah ? so the function is called.

Comment: you can leave the like this too ng-app="" , so the controller is global but even then the script doesnt work

Comment: Please do not learn angular from W3Schools... :(

Comment: anywhere else to get a good grip on angular ?

Comment: Compared to W3Schools? Lots of places, [Angularjs Tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial), [thinkster.io](https://thinkster.io/angulartutorial/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs/). My personal favorite, [PluralSight](http://www.pluralsight.com/search/?searchTerm=angular) in particular their [angularjs fundementals](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/angularjs-fundamentals), and they also have an [angularjs get started](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/angularjs-get-started) which is newer and probably more up to date. PluralSight isn't free but it's well worth it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly certain that the value of `ng-controller` is case sensitive.

So, this:

```
ng-controller="hello"
```

will look for a function with the name: `hello`, not `Hello`.

[Here is a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/o2Jsyxs8GleNM71SXkBQ?p=preview) demonstrating the issue.

Comment: How would you do the same if the file with the data at the server side required an API key to access the json data

Comment: could you do a plunker, if possible, to demonstrate how the call would work with a header that we're sending?

Answer (score 0):

Change your controller code like this.

```
(function () {
  var myApp = angular.module('myModule');

  myApp.controller('hello', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

       $http.get("http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting").then(function(data){
       $scope.greeting=data;
       });

  }]);
})();
```

and in the html

```
{{greeting.data.id}}
```

I checked it in plunker. It is working fine

Comment: thanks a lot. this by the making the controller specific to a certain module yeah ?

Comment: You can use this type of convention when you have mulitple controllers in your application. 'myModule' is kind of namespace(c#) which will be specified in ng-app. And one of he best practice is using IIFE. Please refer to the link below. http://toddmotto.com/minimal-angular-module-syntax-approach-using-an-iife/